# No INSERTs on catalog_product_super_link when using simple_skus column

Tags: mysql, magmi

My CSV file works fine with Magmi for most things, except one: Adding a comma separated list of skus in the "simple_skus" column of a configurable product won't insert rows into either of the tables `catalog_product_super_link` and `catalog_product_relation`. I have another script which relies on rows in these both tables, which now does not work on such imported products.

Using the option "auto match simples skus before configurable" would insert rows here, but using the simple_skus column does not. I cannot use matchable skus because I must follow another pattern for skus.

Shouldn't Magmi insert rows in both of these tables?

Comment: Ok, one issue I had was a typo. It's `simples_skus`, not `simple_skus`. I changed that, imported again, and now I get rows in `catalog_product_super_link` table, but still no rows in `catalog_product_relation`. The missing rows seem to be responsible for not showing the dropdown menu on the frontend view, where one can select a product option from a configurable product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: The CSV file needs to have empty `configurable_attributes` values for the simple products. So, my working CSV file looks like this:

```
sku,name,type,websites,store,attribute_set,tax_class_id,status,visibility,qty,price,cost,url_key,use_config_manage_stock,manage_stock,is_in_stock,description,short_description,meta_keyword,image,simples_skus,size,configurable_attributes
06964615_DBT,Apple pie creme,simple,base,admin,myattributes,0,1,1,1000,3.19,4.41,apple-pie-06964615,1,1,1,,,,apple-pie-creme-06964615.png,,100 ml,
06964621_DBT,Apple pie creme,simple,base,admin,myattributes,0,1,1,1000,5.75,7.77,apple-pie-06964621,1,1,1,,,,apple-pie-creme-06964621.png,,200 ml,
06964615_06964621_DBT,Apple pie creme,configurable,base,admin,myattributes,0,1,4,0,0,0,apple-pie,1,1,1,,,,apple-pie-creme-06964621.png,06964615_DBT,06964621_DBT,,size
```

Comment: Here's a quite good starting point for importing configurable products per Magmi: http://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-configurable-item-processor/